# Range error index invalid value not in range, 0..1 inclusive 2 in dart flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile-application, flutter-dependencies

I am following one flutter app tutorial and I encounter this error:

> Range error index invalid value not in range, 0..1 inclusive 2

Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//void main() {
  //runApp(MyApp());
//}
void main()=>runApp(MyApp()); 
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget{

  @override
 State<StatefulWidget> createState(){
   return MyAppState();

 }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp>{

var questionIndex=0;

  void answerQuestion(){
    setState(() {
      questionIndex=questionIndex+1;
    });
   print(questionIndex);
    //print("answer choosen!");
  }
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){ 

var questions=['What is your favourite colour','what is favourite animal',];

return MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(
appBar:AppBar(title:Text('my first app'),),
body: Column(children:[Text(questions[questionIndex]),
        //RaisedButton(child: Text("Ansewr 1"), onPressed:()=>print("Answer 1"),),
        //RaisedButton(child: Text("Ansewr 1"),onPressed:answerQuestion),
        RaisedButton(child: Text("Ansewr 0"), onPressed:answerQuestion,),
        RaisedButton(child: Text("Ansewr 1"), onPressed:answerQuestion,),



          ],),

),);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modify your code. Maybe that works for you. And don't use setState() method too much. Try learning bLoc archtecture.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
return MyAppState();
 }
}

enum Questions { firstQuestion, secondQuestion }

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
var question = Questions.firstQuestion;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
var questions = [
  'What is your favourite colour',
  'what is favourite animal',
];

return MaterialApp(
  home: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('my first app'),
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Text(questions[question.index]),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Ansewr 0"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              question = Questions.firstQuestion;
            });
          },
        ),
        RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Ansewr 1"),
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              question = Questions.secondQuestion;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: thanks bro, you really give me an insight to this concept on flutter

Answer (score 0):

Your question should contain in which moment the error occurs. But I guess the error appears after you clicked on one of your `RaisedButton`s for the second time in total?

Every time you click on one of your buttons you increase `questionIndex` and rebuild your widgets. In one part of your widget tree, you write `Text(questions[questionIndex])`. Your array `questions` contain two questions. If you start your app `questionIndex=0` so the first question will be shown at `Text(questions[questionIndex])`. If you click a button `questionIndex=1` so the second question will be shown. If you click one of your buttons again you increase `questionIndex` to 2. So now your widget tree tries to get the question at the third position in `questions[questionIndex]`. But there is no third question so your app breaks down.